# Does performing a git rebase -i perform any sort of merging?

Tags: git

If I do `git rebase -i HEAD~n`, is that just squashing or will it do any sort of merging/rebasing? I'm under the impression that I don't have to do something such as `git pull --rebase` afterwards as that would be redundant.

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~n` opens an editor that allows you to provide it a list of instructions for what to do.  What instructions are you giving it?  The default?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull --rebase` does a `git fetch` + `git rebase`. If you're running `git rebase` directly you won't do the `git fetch` step.

Thus you should do `git fetch` + `git rebase -i` if you wish to update to the latest HEAD at the tracked branch. Using `git rebase -i HEAD~n` rewrites the last `n` commits on your branch. The tracked branch is not involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

Whether `git rebase -i HEAD~n` is squashing commits or not depends on what you tell Git to do. The command opens your default editor with a list of the commits you specified (`HEAD~n`'s child up to `HEAD`) and you have to tell Git what to do with each of them. The default action is to pick it, thus to do nothing but reapply it. So if you do not change anything from the default, you are effectively not changing anything, except if there are merges in your list of commits. Merges are ignored by default, so this command would remove the merge and make the history linear instead. But you can also tell Git to not ignore the merges if you are knowing what you are doing.